# jquery each does not loop through all elements?

Tags: jquery

EDIT: this code works fine, overlooked that the divs were stacked on top of eachother, fooled by visual feedback :( excuse me.

I have been searching the each questions here on stackOverflow and reading the jquery doc but I cant find out why this snippet is only placing "bar" in one of the divs. What am I missing here? All examples seem to work this way:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

$(".foo").each(
  function() {
    $(this).append("bar");
  }
);
```

I select all foo class elements, iterate over them with each, in the each function this is the current element right? Seems not though... what am I doing wrong?

I also tried:

`function(index, element) {$(element)` etc. same results.

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/4KuQ8/. Did you put it inside `$(document).ready` in case the second element is defined after the script?

Comment: Is this the exact character-for-character html you are using on your page as well?

Comment: Thanks found my problem!

Comment: @Esailija no so found my mistake how can i close this?

Comment: Edit your question to have your real html, then I can point out the mistake in an answer and get rep

Comment: As a side note, `$(".foo").append("bar")` would work equally fine here - most (if not all) functions manipulating a jQuery set loop internally.

Comment: @Klodder: If your fix was something any of the answers addressed, than accept that answer. If the fix was something completly different, post your own answer and accept it to ensure it may help other users in the future with similar issues or simply delete the question if that is what you prefer.

Comment: @pimvdb yes I know but I need to perform a seperate action on each element with some calculations, thanks though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a function with the index and element params, this will allow you to iterate over the objects jQuery selects.

You can only do this once the document is ready, so make sure it is ready, or wrap in on ready

```
 <div class="foo"></div>
 <div class="foo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".foo").each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).append("bar");
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, your code and the alternate short version (as mentioned by `pimvdb` in the comments on question) works perfectly fine.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3F7X/)

You are most likely having an issue with the code not being in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` or your reference to the jQuery library is missing.

Placing code within [**.ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) ensures the DOM is fully loaded (except images) before your script is executed.